# How do we say ''Please give me your advice'' in Japanese?

Tags: translation

> Please give me your advice

in Japanese. Is あなたのアドバイスを教えてください。 appropriate?

Comment: http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/Please+give+me+advice 「アドバイスをください」/「助言をください」でいいと思います・・

Answer (score 4):

I think you could simply say:

> アドバイスをお[願]{ねが}いします。

or even more simply:

> アドバイスをください。 *lit.* Please give (me) (your) advice.

---

Alternatively you could say:

> アドバイスを｛もらえますか / もらえませんか｝。-- Can I have your advice?

which would sound a bit less direct.

To sound politer, you could say:

> アドバイスを｛いただけますか / いただけませんか｝。-- Could I have your advice?
>   アドバイスをいただきたいのですが。-- I would like to have your advice.
>   etc...

using the humble form いただく.

Comment: You could also use 「[助言]{じょげん}」 in place of 「アドバイス」

Answer (score 2):

I'll use those words:

```
|English |Japanese 　  |
−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−
|advice  |助言,アドバイス|
|give    |ください      |
```

You could say:

> - アドバイスをください
> - [助言]{じょげん}をください

They can be question. This is polite.

> Could you please give me your advice?
>   アドバイスをいただけませんか？
>   [助言]{じょげん}をいただけませんか？

> あなたのアドバイスを[教]{おし}えてください。

I think that is OK, but that is not used commonly.

Answer (score 1):

In this case the most natural expression would be the one below. Wording will change according to the person you are speaking to.

If you are speaking to a friend, then you don't need to use honorific or humble speech.

> 「[相談]{そうだん}にのってもらえる？」
>   Could you give me advice?

If you are speaking to your teacher, you need to use honorific and humble speech.

> 「[相談]{そうだん}にのっていただけますか？」
>   Could I please ask for your advice?

Notice that もらえる has changed into いただけます.

When addressing the teacher, you could also say it like this:

> 「相談にのってください。」

This would express more zeal. While previously you were just asking if the teacher has the time or will to give you advice, now you are desperate to have it. "Please, give me your advice!"

P.S.
You cannot 教える an アドバイス.
You can もらう an アドバイス.

Incorrect: 「アドバイス教えられる？」
Correct: 「アドバイスもらえる？」

Still, アドバイス is a word which came from English and this phrase you can easily sense this influence, i.e. there is a manner of foreign-ness to it.

Answer (score 0):

The word あなた should never be used when addressing a single person, it lacks any kind of respect. Omit the subject completely if you don't know the person's name.

For the form in itself, I think:

> アドバイスを教えていただけませんか。

is the most polite way of asking someone for advice. Other versions also exist:

> アドバイスを教えてもらえませんか。
>   アドバイスを教えてくれませんか。

They all roughly have the same meaning, but the level of formality is slightly different. The first sentence is used for strangers and bosses, the second for teachers (that you are acquainted with) and service staff for example, and the third would be common to use for your homestay family.

いただけませんか asks if it is (not) possible to (humbly) receive something from the other person.

もらえませんか means the same, just a little more casual, but still formal.

くれませんか means to ask if it is (not) possible for the other person to generously give something (in this case: advice).

edit: アドバイスを教えてください。 also exists and is also very formal, might be more appropriate when talking to service staff.

Hope that helps!